# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Not Treating .JPG Extension As An Image; Doesn't Create Thumbnail

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, image-processing, jpeg

My Ubuntu 20.04 desktop isn't treating .JPG as an image.

- It doesn't create a thumbnail.
- When I use video editing software *Kdenlive* only .jpg show.
- But when I double click on a .JPG it does load as an image.

I searched on *Ask Ubuntu*.  I saw the steps for erasing the .cache "Thumbnails" folder.  I did this.  Only specific images recreated their thumbnails after I rebooted the computer.

I am wondering if there is a step I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

The nautilus file manager requires the image size icon to have a minimum height in order to create a thumbnail preview.  While within the nautilus window increase the size using `CTRL +`

[image: nautilus file manager]